# How to fix urls of wordpress site behind reverse proxy server

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, reverse-proxy

I have a WordPress site on IIS 8, let's call it `www.mysite.com`, that I need to isolate behind a proxy server (with IIS 10).

What I have done so far is:

- changed `siteurl` and `home` to `site.mysite.com` (to avoid continuos redirect)
- added site `www.mysite.com` in new server with reverse proxy to `site.mysite.com` (defined in hosts file as old server ip alias) configured as follow

  ```xml
  <configuration>
      <system.webServer>
          <rewrite>
              <outboundRules rewriteBeforeCache="true">
                  <clear />
                  <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1" enabled="true">
                      <match filterByTags="A, Area, Base, Form, Frame, Head, IFrame, Img, Input, Link, Script" pattern="^http(s)?://site.mysite.com/(.*)" />
                      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true" />
                      <action type="Rewrite" value="http{R:1}://www.mysite.com/{R:2}" />
                  </rule>
                  <rule name="RestoreAcceptEncoding" preCondition="NeedRestoringAcceptEncoding" enabled="true">
                      <match serverVariable="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" pattern="^(.*)" />
                      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true" />
                      <action type="Rewrite" value="{HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
                  </rule>
                  <preConditions>
                      <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                          <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                      </preCondition>
                      <preCondition name="NeedRestoringAcceptEncoding">
                          <add input="{HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" pattern=".+" />
                      </preCondition>
                  </preConditions>
              </outboundRules>
              <rules>
                  <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                      <match url="(.*)" />
                      <action type="Rewrite" url="https://site.mysite.com/{R:1}" />
                      <serverVariables>
                          <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
                          <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
                      </serverVariables>
                  </rule>
              </rules>
          </rewrite>
      </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
  ```

**Unfortunately this isn't enough.**

Despite the reverse proxy outbound rule, many scripts, css links and images point to `site.mysite.com` (which is not exposed to the internet) instead of `www.mysite.com`.

Is there a way to fix those links making them refer to `www`?

Are there better solutions?

---

I have never worked with WordPress/PHP and have no knowledge how it builds those urls, so if you need any clarification please be as specific as possible thus I can improve my question.

## UPDATE

If I configure

- in isolated server

  - `siteurl` and `home` to `www.mysite.com`
  - set `127.0.0.1 www.mysite.com` in hosts file
- in exposed server

  - IIS 10 site binding `www.mysite.com` with forward rule to `www.mysite.com`
  - set `WORDPRESS_SERVER_IP www.mysite.com` in hosts file

I get following IIS error:

> Errore HTTP 400.605 - Bad Request
>   The request cannot be routed because it has reached the Max-Forwards limit. The server may be self-referencing itself in request routing topology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the `siteurl` and `home` variables to the value of the proxy server.

If you're exposing your server to the public at `www.mysite.com` then you should set the same values in those variables.

Comment: Keeping the old server to expose `www.mysite.com` as the new server causes the browser to keep redirecting and never shows content.

Comment: I've updated my question based on your answer, could you take a look at it?